# How can I create a snapshot to listen to users being ADDED to my Firestore database?

Tags: swift, database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore. I am trying to listen for when a new user is added. The problem is, each user also has a friends dictionary. So when I use a snapshot, my code is detecting both events of (1) A new user being added and (2) a new friend being added.

I have tries iterating over the document changes data and restricting doc.document.data()["friends"] == nil. Why isn't this working/how can I properly add a restriction to only include when a new user is added?

```
func observeUsers(onSuccess: @escaping(UserCompletion)) {
    Ref().firestoreUserRef.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error with observeUser snapshot")
            return
        }
        querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach { doc in
            //I want to detect that a new user was added, I do not want to detect if a friend was added
            if (doc.type == .added) && doc.document.data()["friends"] == nil {
                guard let dict = querySnapshot else { return }
                for document in dict.documents {
                    var dictionary = [String : Any]()
                    dictionary = document.data()
                    if let user = User.transformUser(dict: dictionary) {
                        onSuccess(user)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is starting from the data model to support the types of queries you want. In this case, when you create a new user (which I assume always has no friends), set the `friends` field explicitly to `null`. This will let you query for all new users:

```
Ref().firestoreUserRef.collection("users").whereField("friends", isEqualTo: NSNull()).addSnapshotListener ...
```

An assumption here is your `transformUser` process will update the document and replace `null` with either a list of friends of an empty array so that it no longer matches the query.